# Quickblox: ClassDefNotFoundError : Smack.smackAndroid in video chat

Tags: android, quickblox

I have used [this](http://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-videochat-android) link to preform videoChat.However, it gives me  `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` which cannot locate : `com.quickblox.module.chat.smack.SmackAndroid` class .I tried changing the preferences of libraries but din't helped.

Here is the log:

```
03-22 18:14:21.476: I/dalvikvm(9908): Could not find method com.quickblox.module.chat.smack.SmackAndroid.init, referenced from method com.quickblox.videochatsample.ui.App.onCreate
03-22 18:14:21.476: W/dalvikvm(9908): VFY: unable to resolve static method 50: Lcom/quickblox/module/chat/smack/SmackAndroid;.init (Landroid/content/Context;)Lcom/quickblox/module/chat/smack/SmackAndroid;
03-22 18:14:21.476: D/dalvikvm(9908): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0003
03-22 18:14:21.481: D/AndroidRuntime(9908): Shutting down VM
03-22 18:14:21.481: W/dalvikvm(9908): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41927700)
03-22 18:14:21.486: E/AndroidRuntime(9908): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-22 18:14:21.486: E/AndroidRuntime(9908): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.quickblox.module.chat.smack.SmackAndroid
03-22 18:14:21.486: E/AndroidRuntime(9908):     at com.quickblox.videochatsample.ui.App.onCreate(App.java:13)
03-22 18:14:21.486: E/AndroidRuntime(9908):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1024)
03-22 18:14:21.486: E/AndroidRuntime(9908):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4684)
03-22 18:14:21.486: E/AndroidRuntime(9908):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:159)
03-22 18:14:21.486: E/AndroidRuntime(9908):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1376)
03-22 18:14:21.486: E/AndroidRuntime(9908):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-22 18:14:21.486: E/AndroidRuntime(9908):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-22 18:14:21.486: E/AndroidRuntime(9908):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
03-22 18:14:21.486: E/AndroidRuntime(9908):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-22 18:14:21.486: E/AndroidRuntime(9908):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-22 18:14:21.486: E/AndroidRuntime(9908):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
03-22 18:14:21.486: E/AndroidRuntime(9908):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
03-22 18:14:21.486: E/AndroidRuntime(9908):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Try to use updated sample https://github.com/QuickBlox/Sample-VideoChat-android

Comment: This is the log of updated sample @Darya

Comment: Make sure that your Eclipse settings configured correctly:


1. http://gyazo.com/78fc70e4f7a72962218cfaacef809b04  

2. http://gyazo.com/557de011128cf33aecd4451ac44bc7b9  

3. http://gyazo.com/0e6939822b3c4e8e2661e4bf0364835e  

4. http://gyazo.com/de818b9000aeef09cb3095fd0fbaef14

Answer (score 2):

go to build path and click on add external jar and add quickbox-android-1.2.2.jar
and go to Order and Export tab and check jarfile checkbox.and clean and rebuild project thats it...

Comment: i have same issue i have already add 2.0 jar with your way but got error   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.quickblox.chat.QBChatService   , at com.quickblox.sample.chat.ui.activities.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:41)

Comment: have you check jarfile checkbox?

Comment: yes i have checked all .... please see this link i have posted my question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28719297/quickblox-chat-in-android-androidruntime-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-qui

Comment: i have add comment on your link try it.